# Can't install Ruby 2.2.0 with rbenv

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed rbenv and ruby-build however, I still can't install Ruby 2.2.0 using rbenv.

```
user@admin:~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build$ rbenv install 2.2.0
Usage: ruby-build [-kvp] <definition> <prefix>
       ruby-build --definitions

  -k/--keep        Do not remove source tree after installation
  -v/--verbose     Verbose mode: print compilation status to stdout
  -p/--patch       Apply a patch from stdin before building
  -4/--ipv4        Resolve names to IPv4 addresses only
  -6/--ipv6        Resolve names to IPv6 addresses only
  --definitions    List all built-in definitions
```

`rbenv install --list` would actually provide the list of available Ruby versions.

There is also no such command `--debug` so I can't look into it.

Also, `type rbenv` would return `rbenv is hashed` instead of a function. :/

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and mine was due to my relative new-ness to Linux... I was trying to use the package manager with `sudo apt-get install` to set up rbenv and ruby-build. It seemed to work, and I was getting the list of installable Ruby versions when I ran `rbenv install -l` so I thought I was on the right track. However, when I typed `rbenv install 2.2.2` it came back with the usage, just like in your case. But when I actually cloned the git repositories for rbenv and then ruby-build, that was when I got it to work.

I.e. you'll need to follow the steps on https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation and https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#installation to get it to work. If you get an error about the directory you're copying to not being empty, use `rm ~/.rbenv/ -rf` to delete whatever is there before you clone again.

Sorry if this doesn't help your situation but this is what I experienced so I thought I would share just in case it helped.

Comment: Yes, using the cloned repo's are the only way it builds correctly. Good solid answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

I checked `~/.bashrc`, and there was no `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH".`
I ran `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> .bashrc` but I had the wrong current directory, so the shell created another .bashrc in the wrong directory.

I put `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"` in `~/bashrc` and `source .bashrc` worked!